Smart status error : what to do to avoid data loss?
I have a large disk (3TB) that is showing smart errors.
It is a data disk (the OS is elsewhere). It is plugged in, but not mounted. At first it refused to boot on the other disk, but I went into the bios and manage to force it to boot the system.
I don't have any backup for this data (I know it's bad) and I don't want to lose it.
I have already researched a bit about what smart is, and I installed and run skdump, which returns the following bold lines:
SMART Disk Health Good: no
Bad Sectors: 1964 sectors
Overall Status: BAD_STATUS
ID# Name                        Value Worst Thres Pretty      Raw            Type    Updates Good Good/Past
  5 reallocated-sector-count      2     2     5  1963 sectors 0xab0700000000 prefail online  no   no
197 current-pending-sector      100   100     0   1 sectors   0x010000000000 old-age online  n/a  n/a

What are the immediate steps I should take to make sure I don't lose any data ?
I know various forms of this question have been asked before, and I read them, but I am not a computer expert and I really need help on what to do in my specific case.
Thanks

Unfortunately, SMART technologies cannot help you with saving your data. Your best option is to make a backup to another media - if you still can access your files.
If you cannot access your files then you probably are out of luck. There are companies that recover data from broken drives but it is expensive. If a commercial solution is to expensive, then try to search the internet for tips and trix that might or might not work, eg "drive freeze".

i don't know whether the data is inaccessible. All i know is that i've received a smart error from the bios, initially preventing me to boot, and then when i managed to boot, i used skdump to confirm there is indeed a problem. I want to apply the correct procedure to first make sure the data is saved, and second assess the health of the disk. For example, if i just mount it with the plan to copy its contents, won't the simple mount cause extra reads to the disk, which i should try to minimize to keep it safe ? I really need to know the precise steps to minimize the risk and prevent data loss
